# React will re-render all children or not?

Tags: reactjs

let's suppose we've got two components like the following

```
class Exa extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('re-render')
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}
```

and

```
class ExaGroup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Exa>
          <Exa className={this.props.name}>
            <Exa>
              <Exa>
                Hi
              </Exa>
            </Exa>
          </Exa>
        </Exa>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So if `ExaGroup`'s prop `name` get changed, how many `re-render` should be printed to the console output?

To my understanding, it will un-mount the entire subtree from the second `Exa` element onward and recreate all children, hence `re-render` should be printed three times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how many `re-render` should be printed to the console output?

It will print 4 times. `ExaGroup` receives new props, which triggers a re-render. Since you have 4 `Exa`, it will print 4 times.

> To my understanding, it will un-mount the entire subtree from the second Exa element onward and recreate all children, hence re-render should be printed three times.

Don't confuse **re-renders** with **re-mounts**. A re-render means that a component - due to a state or prop mutation - goes through the React reconciliation process to figure out which, if any, elements of its tree needs to be updated or recreated.

React will only tear-down and rebuild a the tree of elements following a element type change or a key change. In every other case, React will only *update* the existing element with the appropriate changes.

[More info](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#the-diffing-algorithm)

Comment: Yeah, I am actually more concerned about the teardown part. Will all three nested `Exa` children be teared down if the prop changes?

Comment: That's won't happen. As I explained above, a tear-down **only happens** if the *type* changes (for example from `Exa` to `Foobar` or something) or the *key* prop changes (which you don't have here)

Answer (score 1):

4 times. name is a property of ExaGroup, so react re-renders all ExaGroup component.